# How to retrieve cloudwatch metrics from an list of instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have multiple instances. I need to retrieve some metrics from a subset of them (not all) using aws cli. I have tried specifying the InstanceId multiple times as Dimension, but it only considers on of the values. For example the command above, only returns de metric values for instance i-xxxxxx (ignores i-yyyyyyy)

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics  --namespace AWS/EC2 \
    --metric-name CPUUtilization \
    --statistics Maximum
    --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-yyyyyyyyyy Name=InstanceId,Value=i-xxxxxxxxx \
    --start-time 2018-08-01T00:00:00Z --end-time 2018-08-01T10:00:00Z --period 300
```

One additional comment: the subset is can be obtained by filtering the list of instances using a tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag:app,Values=myapp \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId' --output text
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong API: `get-metric-statistics` is intended to return the time-series data for a single metric, which is identified by all of its dimensions. I suspect that the CLI interprets this field as an associative array, so the second instance ID overwrote the first.

The simplest solution (assuming you're using bash on Linux) is to use a `for` loop to retrieve each set of metrics:

```
for instance in i-yyyyyyyyyy i-xxxxxxxxx
do aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
                  --dimensions "Name=InstanceId,Value=${instance}" \
                  ...
done
```